# Prove $\lim_{n \to \infty} ( \frac{\psi(-1/2+n i )- \psi(-1/2-n i)}{2i}- \frac{n}{n^2+1/4} ) = \frac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: limits, riemann-sum, digamma-function

Consider the sequence:

$$A_n=  \frac{\psi(-1/2+n i )- \psi(-1/2-n i)}{2i}- \frac{n}{n^2+1/4} $$

How would you prove that:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} A_n= \frac{\pi}{2}$$

This sequence converges extremely fast, in fact for $n=10$ we have:

$$\left( \frac{\psi(-1/2+10 i )- \psi(-1/2-10 i)}{2i}- \frac{10}{100+1/4} \right)=  \\ = 1.57079632679489661923132169 \ldots$$

Where all the digits shown are the same as for $\pi/2$.

---

I have found this limit by considering the usual integral $\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{1+x^2}$, using the midpoint rule to derive a Riemann sum, then finding its explicit hypergeometric form, which simplified to the difference of digammas.

I was quite surprised by the accuracy of this method, because it only takes $10$ points to get $25$ correct digits, so my questions are:

- What other proofs can you offer for the limit?
- Why does it converge so fast? Is it because the midpoint rule is very accurate and the integrated function is very nice?

The motivation for this question is of course, generalization of this result, because any integral of the form:

$$\int_a^b \frac{P(x)}{Q(x)} c^x dx$$

where $P,Q$ are polynomials, can be approximated by a hypergeometric Riemann sum.

Comment: @ Yurij S Most naturally you would use the asymptotic expansion $\psi ^{(0)}(z)\simeq -\log \left(\frac{1}{z}\right)-\frac{1}{2 z} -\frac{1}{12 z^2} + ...$

Comment: @ Yurij S I guess you have started with harmonic numbers. Hence the addtional term which vanishes in the limit. ;-)

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze, not really, it was just an unfortunate choice of the starting index for the Riemann sum. I have obtained a hypergeometric function minus $1$, which then simplified to the stated form. I could have avoided that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\psi(-1/2+n i )- \psi(-1/2-n i)}{2i}
&=\frac{\psi(-1/2+n i )- \left(\psi(1/2-n i)-\frac1{-1/2-ni}\right)}{2i}\\
&=\frac{\psi(-1/2+n i )- \psi(1/2-n i)}{2i}+\frac{2n+i}{4n^2+1}\\
&=\frac{\psi(-1/2+n i )- \left(\psi(3/2-n i)-\frac1{1/2-ni}\right)}{2i}+\frac{2n+i}{4n^2+1}\\
&=\frac{\psi(-1/2+n i )- \psi(3/2-n i)}{2i}+\frac{4n}{4n^2+1}\\
&=\frac{\pi\cot{(\pi(3/2-ni))}}{2i}+\frac{4n}{4n^2+1}\\
&=\frac{\pi\cot{(3\pi/2-\pi ni)}}{2i}+\frac{4n}{4n^2+1}\\
&=\frac{\pi\tan{(\pi ni)}}{2i}+\frac{4n}{4n^2+1}\\
&=\frac{\pi i\tanh{(\pi n)}}{2i}+\frac{4n}{4n^2+1}\\
&=\frac{\pi \tanh{(\pi n)}}{2}+\frac{4n}{4n^2+1}\\
\end{align}$$
where I have used the recurrence formula and reflection formula for the digamma function shown [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Reflection_formula). Then our limit is simply
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\pi \tanh{(\pi n)}}{2}=\frac{\pi}2$$
as we have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\tanh{(\pi n)}=1$$

Comment: \@PeterForeman, thanks, this is a very pretty closed form for the Riemann sum in question, a nice roundabout proof for the classical result

Answer (score 2):

We shall express the polygamma function $\psi^{(0)}(z)$ in terns of the $\Gamma(z)$ function and continue the derivation using the latter.

Let

$$f(n) = \frac{1}{2 i}\left(\psi ^{(0)}\left(-\frac{1}{2}+ n i\right)-\psi^{(0)} \left(-\frac{1}{2}- n i\right)\right)$$

This is a simplified version of the expression of the OP which neglects the term

$$- \frac{n}{n^2+1/4}$$

which is irrelevant for the limit.

Remembering the definition of the digamma function

$$\psi^{(0)}(z)=\frac{\partial\log (\Gamma (z))}{\partial z}$$

we are led to define the function

$$g(n) = -\frac{1}{2}\left(\log\left(\Gamma(-\frac{1}{2} + n i)\right) + \log\left(\Gamma(-\frac{1}{2} - n i)\right)   \right)$$

so that

$$\frac{\partial g(n)}{ \partial n} = f(n)\tag{*}$$

Now $g$ can be written as

$$g(n) =-\frac{1}{2}\log\left(\Gamma(-\frac{1}{2} + n i)  \Gamma(-\frac{1}{2} - n i) \right) = -\frac{1}{2}\log\left(\frac{4 \pi }{(1+4 n^2) \cosh(n \pi)}\right)  $$

Here we have used the properties of $\log$ and the relation

$$\Gamma \left(-\frac{1}{2}+ n i\right) \Gamma \left(-\frac{1}{2}- n i\right)=\frac{4 \pi }{4 n^2+1}\frac{1}{\cosh(\pi n)}$$

which is a consequence of Euler's reflexion formula $\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z) = \frac{\pi}{\sin(z)}$ for $z=\frac{3}{2}+i n$ and twofold application of $ \Gamma(x+1)= x\Gamma(x)$.

Now, using $(*)$ we get

$$f(n) = \frac{\pi  \left(4 n^2+1\right) \tanh (\pi  n)+8 n}{8 n^2+2}$$

from which the limit is easily obtained

$$\lim_{n\to \infty } \, f(n)=\frac{\pi }{2}$$

**Discussion**

The same limit is obtained for the more general expression

$$F(n) = \frac{1}{2 i}\left(\psi ^{(0)}\left(a + i b(n)\right)-\psi^{(0)} \left(a-  i b(n)\right)\right)$$

where $a$ is real an $b(n)$ is a real function going to $\infty$ with $n$.

Using the asymptotic expansion

$$\psi ^{(0)}(z\to \infty)\simeq -\log \left(\frac{1}{z}\right)-\frac{1}{2 z}$$

we see that the limit boils down to

$$\frac{1}{2 i}\log(\frac{a-i b(n)}{a+i b(n)}) \simeq \frac{1}{2 i}\log(-1) = \frac{\pi}{2}$$

Comment: Very nice, thank you!